# Issue Building new application with QT 5.8 Ubuntu

Tags: qt, ubuntu, compiler-errors

I have installed QT 5.8 in Ubuntu 16.04 using QT's installer (Online one) and once installed I tried to create a GUI application with the basic code for a MainWindow that it gives you as a starting point but it doesn't compile.

I have done exactly the same thing in another machine in Windows 10 and Zorin OS (Ubuntu based distro) and it works perfectly.

When trying to compile I get the following errors:

```
18:37:57: Running steps for project aLAL...
18:37:57: Configuration unchanged, skipping qmake step.
18:37:57: Starting: "/usr/bin/make" 
g++ -c -pipe -O2 -std=gnu++11 -Wall -W -D_REENTRANT -fPIC -DQT_DEPRECATED_WARNINGS -DQT_NO_DEBUG -DQT_WIDGETS_LIB -DQT_GUI_LIB -DQT_CORE_LIB -I../aLAL -I. -I/home/twistx77/Qt/5.8/gcc_64/include -I/home/twistx77/Qt/5.8/gcc_64/include/QtWidgets -I/home/twistx77/Qt/5.8/gcc_64/include/QtGui -I/home/twistx77/Qt/5.8/gcc_64/include/QtCore -I. -isystem /usr/include/libdrm -I. -I/home/twistx77/Qt/5.8/gcc_64/mkspecs/linux-g++ -o main.o ../aLAL/main.cpp
In file included from /home/twistx77/Qt/5.8/gcc_64/include/QtCore/qcompilerdetection.h:996:0,
                 from /home/twistx77/Qt/5.8/gcc_64/include/QtCore/qglobal.h:97,
                 from /home/twistx77/Qt/5.8/gcc_64/include/QtGui/qtguiglobal.h:43,
                 from /home/twistx77/Qt/5.8/gcc_64/include/QtWidgets/qtwidgetsglobal.h:43,
                 from /home/twistx77/Qt/5.8/gcc_64/include/QtWidgets/qmainwindow.h:43,
                 from /home/twistx77/Qt/5.8/gcc_64/include/QtWidgets/QMainWindow:1,
                 from ../aLAL/mainwindow.h:4,
                 from ../aLAL/main.cpp:1:
/usr/include/c++/5/utility:213:5: error: ‘qtruct’ does not name a type
     qtruct _Build_index_tuple
     ^
/usr/include/c++/5/utility:219:12: error: ‘_Build_index_tuple’ is not a class template
     struct _Build_index_tuple<0>
            ^
/usr/include/c++/5/utility:220:5: error: explicit specialization of non-template ‘std::_Build_index_tuple’
     {
     ^
In file included from /usr/include/c++/5/bits/stl_map.h:63:0,
                 from /usr/include/c++/5/map:61,
                 from /home/twistx77/Qt/5.8/gcc_64/include/QtCore/qmetatype.h:55,
                 from /home/twistx77/Qt/5.8/gcc_64/include/QtCore/qobject.h:54,
                 from /home/twistx77/Qt/5.8/gcc_64/include/QtWidgets/qwidget.h:45,
                 from /home/twistx77/Qt/5.8/gcc_64/include/QtWidgets/qmainwindow.h:44,
                 from /home/twistx77/Qt/5.8/gcc_64/include/QtWidgets/QMainWindow:1,
                 from ../aLAL/mainwindow.h:4,
                 from ../aLAL/main.cpp:1:
/usr/include/c++/5/tuple:1074:29: error: ‘std::_Build_index_tuple’ is not a template
       typedef typename std::_Build_index_tuple<std::tuple_size<
                             ^
/usr/include/c++/5/tuple:1075:54: error: typedef name may not be a nested-name-specifier
  typename std::remove_reference<_Tp>::type>::value>::__type __type;
                                                      ^
/usr/include/c++/5/tuple:1075:54: error: expected ‘;’ at end of member declaration
/usr/include/c++/5/tuple:1075:61: error: declaration does not declare anything [-fpermissive]
  typename std::remove_reference<_Tp>::type>::value>::__type __type;
                                                             ^
/usr/include/c++/5/tuple: In constructor ‘std::pair<_T1, _T2>::pair(std::piecewise_construct_t, std::tuple<_Args1 ...>, std::tuple<_Args2 ...>)’:
/usr/include/c++/5/tuple:1160:16: error: expected nested-name-specifier before ‘_Build_index_tuple’
       typename _Build_index_tuple<sizeof...(_Args1)>::__type(),
                ^
/usr/include/c++/5/tuple:1160:16: error: expected ‘(’ before ‘_Build_index_tuple’
/usr/include/c++/5/tuple:1161:16: error: expected nested-name-specifier before ‘_Build_index_tuple’
       typename _Build_index_tuple<sizeof...(_Args2)>::__type())
                ^
/usr/include/c++/5/tuple:1161:16: error: expected ‘(’ before ‘_Build_index_tuple’
Makefile:877: recipe for target 'main.o' failed
make: *** [main.o] Error 1
18:37:58: The process "/usr/bin/make" exited with code 2.
Error while building/deploying project aLAL (kit: Desktop Qt 5.8.0 GCC 64bit)
When executing step "Make"
18:37:58: Elapsed time: 00:01.
```

I have tried to find a solution looking on the Internet but I can't figure it out.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your C++ standard library header `utility` has been corrupted:

```
/usr/include/c++/5/utility:213:5: error: ‘qtruct’ does not name a type
     qtruct _Build_index_tuple
```

I'd try changing `qtruct` to `struct` in that file. Or you could reinstall the standard library

Comment: Thanks but that doesn't help. I think the problem might have something to do with this message I get when I try to run QtCreator from console " No tool chain set up in kit "Desktop Qt 5.8.0 GCC 64bit" for "C"" Although I have check and it seems that compilers are autodetected correctly.

Comment: @twistx77: what happened when you tried it? (1) nothing, because you couldn't edit the system header. (2) some other error message (if so, what?) (3) something else...